# Regex taking forever on short string.

Tags: python, regex

I'm looking through a bunch of strings, trying to match some with the following pattern.

```
location_pattern = re.compile( r"""
                                \b
                                (?P<location>
                                    ([A-Z]\w*[ -]*)+[, ]+
                                    (
                                      [A-Z]{2}
                                        |
                                      [A-Z]\w+\ *\d  ##
                                    )
                                )
                                \b 
                                """, flags=re.VERBOSE)
```

Now this regex runs ok on almost all my data set, but it takes **forever**  (well, 5 seconds) on *this* particular string:

```
' JAVASCRIPT   SOFTWARE   ARCHITECT,   SUCCESSFUL   SERIAL'
```

There are a bunch of strings like this one (all caps, lots of space chars) at some point in my input data and the program is greatly slowed when it hits it. I tried taking out different parts of the regex, and it turns out the culprit is the
**\ *\d** at the end of the commented line.

I'd like to understand how this is causing the regex validation to take so long.

Can anyone help?

Comment: What is so unclear about this question (to the close voters)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why removing `\ *\d` works is because you just turn the example in the question from a *non-matching* case into a *matching* case. In a backtracking engine, a matching case usually takes (much) less time than a non-matching case, since in non-matching case, the engine must exhaust the search space to come to that conclusion.

Where the problem lies is correctly pointed out by Fede (the explanation is rather hand-waving and inaccurate, though).

```
([A-Z]\w*[ -]*)+
```

Since `[ -]*` is optional and `\w` can match `[A-Z]`, the regex above degenerates to `([A-Z][A-Z]*)+`, which matches the classic example of catastrophic backtracking `(A*)*`. The degenerate form also shows that the problem manifests on long strings of uppercase letter.

The fragment by itself doesn't cause much harm. However, as long as the sequel (whatever follows after the fragment above) fails, it will cause catastrophic backtracking.

Here is one way to rewrite it (without knowing your exact requirement):

```
[A-Z]\w*(?:[ -]+[A-Z]\w*)*[ -]*
```

By forcing `[ -]+` to be at least once, the pattern can no longer match a string of uppercase letter in multiple ways.

Comment: I don't know who, but downvoting every single answers in a bad question is not constructive at all. Just vote to close or downvote the question if you think the question is unclear (which is not the case here).

Comment: You win by explaining why my assumption was wrong, teaching me the common pattern that caused the problem and providing an example that avoids it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Additionally to Greg's answer, you have also this pattern:

```
([A-Z]\w*[ -]*)+
        ^----^-^---- Note embedded quantifiers!
```

Using quantifiers inside a repeated group (even worse 2 quantifiers as you have) usually **generates catastrophic backtracking issues**. Hence, I'd re think the regex.

Comment: I can offer you another regex if you add more sample data and your expected output by updating my answer later.

Comment: `Using quantifiers inside a repeated group generates catastrophic backtracking issues` This is not always the case, and that is only a necessary condition, not sufficient condition.

Comment: @nhahtdh I know, you are right I will add usually since it isn't a law lol. Thanks